# replacing element np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this nparray :

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

and I want to do something like this :

```
for item in array :
        if item[0] == 1:
            item=[0.8,0.20,0,0,0]
        elif item[1] == 1:
            item=[0.20,0.80,0,0,0]
        elif item[3] == 1:
            item=[0,0,0,0.8,0.2]
        elif item[4] == 1:
            item=[0,0,0,0.2,0.8]
        else:
            [0,0,1,0,0]
```

I try this :

```
def conver_probs2(arg):
    test= arg
    test=np.where(test==[1.,0.,0.,0.,0.], [0.8,0.20,0.,0.,0.],test)
    return test
```

but the result is this :

```
[[0.  0.2 0.  0.  1. ]
 [0.8 0.2 0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.2 1.  0.  0. ]
 ...
 [0.  0.2 1.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.2 0.  0.  1. ]
 [0.8 0.2 0.  0.  0. ]]
```

not what I want ... any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to iterate over the indices.

Then it'd be possible for you to reuse the same for loop that you showed like this:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
  if array[i][0] == 1:
    array[i] = [0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0] 
  ...
```

Comment: yes sometimes is better to keep it VERY simple :-) 'code' for item in array 'code' was not working ...

Answer (score 0):

If your replacement array has the same shape as your target you can do this:

```
mask = target[target[:, 0] == 1]
target[mask] = replacements[mask]
```

here is a simple test

```
test_target = np.eye(4)
test_target[2:, 0] = 1
replacements = np.ones((4, 4)) * 42
```

Before using np.where try boolean indexing first. Usually it is what you want.